# How to add http status code to the html report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way I can add the failed http status code to my html report from JMeter when it triggered from command line. I can find them in the jtl file.

I am triggering from command line using the following command

```
jmeter -J jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false -n -t "C:\Performancetest.jmx" -l "C:\PerformanceReport\Test1.jtl" -e -o "C:\PerformanceReport\Report"
```

The following is my sample result

[image]

error details from the report,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way of adding the status code to HTML Reporting Dashboard, however you can:

1. Add status code to the assertion failure message like:

   ```
   prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
       assertionResult.setFailureMessage(assertionResult.getFailureMessage() + ', status code: ' + prev.getResponseCode())
   }
   ```

   as the result you will get the following output:

   [image]
2. Add status code to the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label like:

   ```
   prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ', status code: ' + prev.getResponseCode())
   ```

   as the result you will have the following output:

   [image]

The code snippets are to be added to [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and `prev` stands for the associated [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on various JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.